# Navigation is unreachable

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, auth0

I am using auth0 to do authentication for my ionic 4 app. I am getting an error:

Note: in the domain, I have entered my auth0 domain.

Navigation is unreachable:

```
io.ionic.starter://{domain}/cordova/io.ionic.starter/callback?code=AjSUytLs4jjrzWxy&state=69XZqH36R0BaG1TyzARmmKxzHHtaOuzWBddEhHcQ2ZU
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Auth0 side everything looks to be working as expected as we see the callback occurring with the code & state. However while digging into the `Navigation is unreachable` error you referenced I see people in the past have found this error as a result of forgetting to remove some Brackets ({, }) around their App ID when they were adding cordova-plugin-customurlsheme. This may or may not be the case for you as well. However it is hard to know for sure without any additional details on this front. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I had to change my ionic package id. For some reason, when I was building the app, the AndroidManifest.xml file had android:scheme with the previous package id.  Eg,
`<data android:scheme="io.ionic.starter" />`
So, I had to delete the www folder and platforms/android folder and build it again. This fixed it for me.